# Java Thread communicaton

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am doing a project in which I must make threads communicate.

For instance

I have two thread arrays, `c[100]` and `e[10]`. (customers and employees)

Once a customer say `c[3]` acquires a semaphore to let it speak with one of the employees say employee `e[5]`, how do I associate the `Customer` object represented by the thread `c[3]` to the `Employee` object `e[5]`, and let them pass info back and forth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping data between threads with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602904/piping-data-between-threads-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple techniques for allowing threads to communicate information.  The simplest way is a mutex over shared state.  One of the most classically scalable ways is message queues.  The way that you need to use depends on the statement of your homework assignment.

In general, protect shared state with your synchronization primitive (be it a mutex or semaphore or whatever), and let unshared state run normally.  If you have employees and customers, perhaps they communicate via a "mail slot" that they share.  Protect that mail slot with your semaphore to prevent one from trying to read while the other is writing (or vice-versa), and you'll have the primary strategy that you need.

Comment: I am still not sure I understand how to do it.  I guess the best way to explain this is think of a grocery store.  You have multiple customers that c[0-99] that could go to any available cashier e[0-10].  Once the cashier has a customer at their checkout line, they must communicate by the customer giving the cashier the groceries, then the cashier must give the total back to the customer that handed it the groceries, then the customer must look in their wallet and make sure they have enough money.  So with a message queue, how would you differentiate info that should go to each entitiy?

Comment: So I guess back to the original question, how do i associate the two objects represented by each thread?  Customer with Employee so that they can exchange info.

Comment: You need to read The Java Tutorials on Concurrency http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: So define your communication protocol:  C gives Groceries to E.  E gives Cost to C.  C gives money to E (or gives nothing to E).  If E got money, E gives groceries back to C.  During any given step, both threads aren't going to be doing anything concurrently, so you can use a simple blocking mechanism to do your thing.  You may also choose to associate a Queue of Customers with each employee (the queue by the checkout counter at the grocery store.)

Answer (score 0):

Another ways is by message passing. For instance you can one object subscribe to a listener for events. When the other thread causes a change, then it let all listeners know of the event and all listeners get notified of the change.

Another possible solution is to use piped streams or piped reades (i.e. PidedInputStrean, PipedOutputStream, PipedReader, PipedWriter). In this scheme, one thread writes in one side of the pipe, and the other thread reads the other side.

And I am pretty sure there are several other ways to do it.